# Creating mock IdP for sending SAML messages

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, saml

I'm new to SAML and exchange between **Identity Providers** (IdP) and **Service Providers** (SP) and in app I'm currently working on (.NET MVC) we have IdP that store credentials of users and have its own validation.

I was wondering how can I mock this communication between my app and IdP?

We have a problem with testing because when running in debug mode redirect url doesn't go to localhost.. Is there any library that will help me mock this behaviour of communicating with SAML messages that will send me successfull credentials from mock IdP.